# how avoid Where clause condition if we send null or "" values

Tags: sql, parameters

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id = $id && name LIKE %$name%;
```

this is a kind of filtering code.When I input data inside input field this sql statement trigger using Ajax.But my problem is when I send 'id' as "" using PHP, I need to avoid this condition [id = $id] in SQL.I i need it like this,

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name LIKE %$name%;
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Seems like a X/Y problem. Anything stopping you from validating the ID field on the client side and simply firing a different query when it is empty?

Comment: not X/Y, I just need to avoiding AND condition if parameter is null or ""

Comment: Yeah but why do you need to do that in the SQL query? Wouldn't it be easier in php?

Comment: but i need to to it in that way according to my problem :(

Comment: So the query string you posted isn't actually valid sql. Is that how you assemble your query string? Post the code around it

Answer (score 0):

The following query would solve your problem

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE 
(case when $id is null or $id = '' then   id =id 
else id =$id END)     and name LIKE %$name%;
```